# NBA_API: why is this Python code returning an empty dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, nba-api

I am simply attempting to pull all of today's games; later I will merge team statistics onto it, but that's a different question.

My question is, why does the code below return an empty dataframe? I can print the results using a for loop -- that's how I got the desired output below -- but I cannot put them into a dataframe for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```
from nba_api.live.nba.endpoints import scoreboard
import pandas as pd

todayBoard = scoreboard.ScoreBoard()
ScoreBoardDate = todayBoard.score_board_date
games = todayBoard.games.get_dict()

todayGames = pd.DataFrame()

for game in games:
    todayGames['GAME_ID']=game['gameId']
    todayGames['AWAY']=game['awayTeam']['teamTricode']
    todayGames['HOME']=game['homeTeam']['teamTricode']

todayGames
```

The expected output for 2024-03-21 should be:

```
GAME_ID AWAY HOME
0022301004 NOP ORL
0022301005 SAC WAS
0022301006 CHI HOU
0022301007 BKN MIL
0022301008 UTA DAL
0022301009 NYK DEN
0022301010 ATL PHX
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1. `games` is a list of dictionaries, so you can't assign its values to a pandas dataframe the way you're trying to do.
2. If you could do that, you'd be overwriting the values on each loop. To avoid that, you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

You can get the values you want from `games` into a new dict `todayGames`, and then use that create a dataframe:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# rest of the code omitted...

todayGames = defaultdict(list)

for game in games:
    todayGames["GAME_ID"].append(game["gameId"])
    todayGames["AWAY"].append(game["awayTeam"]["teamTricode"])
    todayGames["HOME"].append(game["homeTeam"]["teamTricode"])

df = pd.DataFrame(todayGames)
```

```
      GAME_ID AWAY HOME
0  0022301004  NOP  ORL
1  0022301005  SAC  WAS
2  0022301006  CHI  HOU
3  0022301007  BKN  MIL
4  0022301008  UTA  DAL
5  0022301009  NYK  DEN
6  0022301010  ATL  PHX
```